# jqMobi - How to dynamically add a panel from another page

Tags: jqmobi

I am using [jqMobi](http://www.jqmobi.com) ( NOT jQuery Mobile ) and I would like to be able to dynamically load a panel with some remote html page and then navigate to it.  I have read [the documentation](http://api.jqmobi.com/#%24.ui.addContentDiv%28id,content,title%29;) that shows how to add a new panel with html in it, but what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
$.ui.addContentDiv("newDiv","somePage.html","Some Title");
```

I know that I could do something like this:

```
$.get("somePage.html",function(data){
    $.ui.addContentDiv("newDiv",data,"Some Title");
    $.ui.loadContent("newDiv", false, false, "up");
});
```

But I'm wondering if there is something better out there.  Also, the above method does nothing if there is a failure, so any suggestions that you may have about that would be appreciated.  As far as I can tell, there is no `failure` callback for the `get` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way - just link to the HTML page and it handles the xhr request for you.  data-persist-ajax caches it in the dom, so future request do not load it.

```
<a href="somePage.html" data-persist-ajax="true">My Page</a>
```

Comment: ah yes, I see that here  http://www.jqmobi.com/documentation.php#jqUi/jqui_anchors
Can you tell me if I can also change the page header title in this link as well?  something like <a href="somePage.html" data-persist-ajax="true" data-page-title="My Page Title">My Page</a> The reason I ask is because now that I load the the pages with your suggested method, the header has this big long URL in it.  thanks

Comment: nevermind.  I looked at the GIT source and see that you are using anchor.title for the header title on line 4038 of the jq.ui.js file.  So now I see that I just need to add `title="My Page Title"` to the anchor tag.  thanks